# Create a report to show on an account

Tags: reporting

I want to create a report that shows as a report chart on the component. However, I don't know how to create a report for just one account.

I want to create a Pie Chart, which shows the following data:

Number of Vans
Number of Cars
Number of Motorbikes

How would I go about that?
Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can start [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/reports_5.htm) or [HERE](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/reports_embed_pagelayout.htm) to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you - I figured it out now. I didn't realise that the report charts that you put on the account detail page are actually filtered by ID.